# How is application sandbox implemented in Android?

Tags: android, sandbox, android-source, android-security

I'm interested in understanding the implementation of application sandbox in Android. My understanding is that it is by creating user accounts for each application and giving appropriate permissions. Also, how is the call to internal storage mapped to the app's storage? Any elaboration or pointer to relevant material will be helpful.

Comment: See documentation on android security here: https://source.android.com/security/overview/kernel-security.html